# Is it mandatory to create a copy of View before assigning an event handler in Android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I am trying to set `OnClickListener` on an `Android` button in Kotlin file. Unlike java file, where I can declare button variable at the class level and initialize it in `onCreate` method and assign ClickListener at the same time as:

```
Button inlineButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        inlineButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_inline);
        inlineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new NotificationToast(MainActivity.this, "Inline Button");
            }
        });
    }
```

when I try to follow similar pattern I get an error with the following message:
[image]

I can only set the event handler only when I create a copy of button with following code:

```
var inlineButton : Button? = null;

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    inlineButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_inline)
    val inlineButtonCopy = inlineButton;

    if (inlineButtonCopy != null) {
        inlineButtonCopy.setOnClickListener({
            NotificationToast(this,inlineButtonCopy.text.toString()).Show();
        })
    }

}
```

I was wondering if it is not possible to create only a single instance of Button on top level, initialize it in oncreate, and set event handler. If I can create only a single instance, I can use the event to change the property of the same button. Is it the default behavior or am I missing something.

Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Comment: Technically, it's not a copy. It's just a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Kotlin** you don't need to define the `Id's` of the XML component.
you can directly access with the help of `Id's` are already defined in your XML.

let suppose you defined the `Button` Id in XML is `btn_inline`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btn_inline.setOnClickListener({
        NotificationToast(this,inlineButtonCopy.text.toString()).Show();
    })
}
```

Also, make sure that something like this should be present there in the `import` section.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Just check at your end.

Comment: Yes it worked when i accessed the button directly using its id. thanks

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin you don't need to describe the Button. You can directly call the id and set Listener. It is easier than java. Just don't get confused in your Id's

```
btn_inline.setOnClickListener({
    NotificationToast(this,inlineButtonCopy.text.toString()).Show();
})
```

Comment: I got it, my question is I am not able to cal btn_setOnClickListener in the first place.

Comment: @ShresthaGanesh can you provide the screenshot of what is error when trying to use my code ?

Comment: [Join this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203979/android-help-room) so i can help you out.

Comment: ya sure.. its the second image in the description.

Comment: ya it worked after accessing the button directly and not using find view by id .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **[Late-Initialized Property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables)**:

```
private lateinit var inlineButton: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    inlineButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_inline)
    inlineButton.setOnClickListener {
        NotificationToast(this,inlineButtonCopy.text.toString()).Show();
    }
}
```